# WAMP Wordpress how to work together on different LAN

Tags: lan, wamp, wordpress

My group and I are students working on Wordpress with WAMP installed on each group member's individual computer- I mention that we are students because I ask that any solutions be considerate of costs.

Our issue is that we only have limited times to work at school so most of our work on our Wordpress is happening at home, where obviously we have different LAN (we live far apart). I was wondering if there was any way, when our group is separated at our own homes and different LAN, to be able to work on our website together. We are beginners in all this and are looking forward to any help.

Comment: Make the Wordpress site available over the internet? Forward port 80 to the machine that is running Wordpress? (assuming you have password etc in place). Otherwise, there are are virtual private network options to create a virtual LAN; but recommending any of them is beyond the scope of this site (it is relatively easy to find them by searching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) make one of you's individual computer available to everybody else when at home. Either create a VPN that can project others in that home environment's network, or open up the http/https and FTP/SFTP/SAMBA ports to the Internet. the first solution is more secure, the second requires you paying attention to exactly what you share and implementing a security mechanism for each protocol.

2) get some free/dirty cheap shared hosting or rent a cheap VPS everybody can access at the same time. Shared hosting can set you back 1$ per year, VPS 1$ per month. This has some notable advantages but may cost you money.

Comment: So I did some research and I have arrived at using Bluehost as my shared hosting. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RichardLiu that is surely up to the task but in this field there are so many providers suitable for your needs that it's hard to recommend one over another. If what you found is ok for you (price-wise) then don't waste any more time looking around. On the other hand, if you want to make a more informed choice, I suggest you take a look at the offers and reviews on [lowendtalk](https://www.lowendtalk.com/).